# How can i select only one li?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I need to make reservation system for test with HTML, CSS, JS. i need to change color of border from li's. But i need to select only one li if i select one it must be add class, when i click to other one it need to delete class from first li.

```
const staff = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alex Rosetta",
        "email": "alexyrosetta@egmail.com",
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/LJnNhRF/unsplash-279x-IHym-PYY.png",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Maria July",
        "email": "mariajuly@egmail.com",
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/3FhkswY/unsplash-IF9-TK5-Uy-KI.png",
    }
];



staff.map(({ id, name, email, image }) => {

    const list = document.querySelector('.myUl');

    list.innerHTML += `<li class="repoFolder" data-value="${id}">

    <div class="doc-photo">
        <img src="${image}" />
    </div>
    <div class="doc-infos">
        <p class="name">${name}</p>
        <p class="mail">${email}</p>
    </div>
</li>`;
});

var items = document.querySelectorAll(".myUl li");
var tab = [], index;

// function rootFolder() {
//     alert(items.getAttribute('data-value'));
// }

// for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
//     items[i].onclick = function (e) {
//         alert(e.getAttribute('data-value'));
//     };
// }


for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = function () {
        console.log(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
        if (this.classList.contains('my-class')) {
            this.classList.remove('my-class');
          } else {
            this.classList.add('my-class');
          }
        

    };
}
```

i tried this, but didnt work

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = function () {
        console.log(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
        if (document.querySelector(".myUl li").classList.contains('my-class')) {
            document.querySelector(".myUl li").classList.remove('my-class');
            this.classList.add('my-class');
          } else {
            this.classList.add('my-class');
          }
        

    };
}
```

Can someone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it helped me so much!! I love you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns a new array of transformed elements. Since you're also working with template strings you may as well use that to your advantage. `map` over the data and return a new (joined) array of HTML strings, and join that up into one HTML string. You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add that to the list element.

The next step is to use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) - attach one listener to the list element and have that watch for events as they bubble up the DOM from its child elements (ie its list items).

Once it catches an event it first checks that the event occurred within a list item, removes the "active" class from all the list items, and then adds one to the item that fired the event.

```js
const staff=[{id:1,name:"Alex Rosetta",email:"alexyrosetta@egmail.com",image:"https://i.ibb.co/LJnNhRF/unsplash-279x-IHym-PYY.png"},{id:2,name:"Maria July",email:"mariajuly@egmail.com",image:"https://i.ibb.co/3FhkswY/unsplash-IF9-TK5-Uy-KI.png"}];

// Returns a joined array of HTML strings
function getHTML(data) {
  return staff.map(obj => {
    const { id, name, email, image } = obj;
    return `
      <li class="repoFolder" data-value="${id}">
        <div class="doc-photo">
          <img src="${image}" alt="Image of ${name}" />
        </div>
        <div class="doc-infos">
          <p class="name">${name}</p>
          <p class="mail">${email}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    `;
  }).join('');
}

// Select the list element and add a listener to it
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', handleList);

// Call `getHTML` with the staff data and insert it
// into the list element
list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getHTML(staff));

// Use the list element to grab all its list items
const items = list.querySelectorAll('li');

// When the listener on the list element catches an
// event check that it's a descendant of a list item,
// remove the "active" classes from the list items,
// and then add one the list item that caught the event
function handleList(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('li')) {
    const parent = e.target.closest('li');
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
    parent.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.active { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggle` instead of `add` and `remove`. As second argument you can pass a boolean: let it be true when the iterated item is the clicked one:

```
for (const clickedItem of items) {
    clickedItem.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (const item of items) {
            item.classList.toggle('my-class', item === clickedItem);
        }
    });
}
```

Not related, but don't use `.map` for iteration when you don't use its return value. Then use `.forEach`.